# jboss AS 7 clusterring connect master slave with jms queue

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss7.x, cluster-computing, hornetq

I use jboss 7 and I want to implement the following configuration.

I want to have a master node that produces messages and place them into a queue. In the domain there will be slaves which will listen to this queue and consume the messages as they arrive. I deployed the corresponding projects in the master and slaves.

My problem is that when the master produces messages, it places in the queue and they remain there, the slaves do not consume them. It seems that the slaves don't work.

Is this configuration possible to be implemented?

Comment: Is there any significance of master-slave here ? Just looking at this from a JMS perspective, this looks like a simple single-producer-multiple-consumers scenario, which is a simple JMS pattern. It is what you will get by default with a single queue listened to by multiple listeners (consumers).